# Pass Parameter into Modules

Tags: angular

I have 3 modules: AddressModule, CustomerModule and CustomerReportingModule.

AddressModule has its own routes and components and is responsible for displaying/editing an address for a customer. It needs the customer/customerId to fetch its data.

CustomerModule and CustomerReportingModule should reuse AddressModule.

Currently I was thinking to use lazy loading for my AddressModule but this is not mandatory.

How can I pass in the customer/customerId into the AddressModule so it can load its data?

Comment: How do you store the `customerId` in the rest of your application, for example in `CustomerModule` and `CustomerReportingModule`?

Comment: Couldnt you just use the route? you look at the activated route in AddressModule and extract the CustomerID

Comment: @FredrikLundin - I have a specific store in both modules which knows which customer is selected. I thought about using this store but than the AddressModule has to know about the other module and its store.

Comment: @Jan - Yes that would be an option but I would need to know on which route parent level the parameter exists and therefore I have knowlegde about the other modules in my AdressModule.

Comment: Every provider added at a module level will be available in an application wide scope. Meaning if you provide the store in the `CustomerModule` you can inject it in `AddressModule` too. Just fyi :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use service to share the data between those modules. You can have this service, imported at the main module provider and hence can be used in all other modules and share the data.

The service can have functions to set and get values and hence you can make use of these functions in services to get your required data